# How to execute pytest fixture on each parameter for test function?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

In my current setup of end-to-end tests I am using Selenium. I have a fixture that looks something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def browser(request):
    # Here I do a basic setup
    # Setting up accounts from configuration based on input from test function
    # Initializing webdriver wrapper with this data
    # yield driver
    # teardown
```

So far I was only using parameters for a fixture and typical test function would look like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('browser', [(SomeEnum, AnotherEnum1),
                                    (SomeEnum, AnotherEnum2)], indirect=True)
def some_test(browser):
```

This will result in two tests:

- `some_test[broswer0]`
- `some_test[browser1]`

I am trying to combine parameters for a function and parameters for a fixture now, so test function looks like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('browser', [([SomeEnum1, SomeEnum2], AnotherEnum)], indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1,param2', [(DifferentEnum, False), (DifferentEnum2, True)])
def some_test(browser, param1, param2):
```

This setup will result in 2 tests, which I want:

- some_test[DifferentEnum-False-browser0]
- some_test[DifferentEnum2-True-browser0]

If I run tests individually, everything is fine. But if I run them together, first one will finish and pass and it seems that second one doesn't go through the fixture at all, but browser session just stays open.

What I need to change for fixture to be executed for each of the tests?

Comment: `scope="function"`?

Comment: Yes exactly, that was the problem, I thought I have already answered it for myself. If you want, you can answer it and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrow the scope of the `browser` fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def browser(request):
    ...
```

or just drop it completely since `function` is the default scope.

```
@pytest.fixture
def browser(request):
    ...
```